# How to avoid missing, incomplete files between branches and environments when making Amplify infrastructure changes between branches

Tags: aws-amplify

I have two env `dev` and `main` in AWS Amplify. Multiple times now, I have created an infrastructure feature in `dev` and then run the following to move it to `main`:

```
 1. (dev) amplify push 
2. git checkout main 
3. amplify env checkout main 
4. git merge dev 
5. (main) amplify push
```

However what is shown in the infrastructure change preview is not what was present in `dev`. I believe it had to do with missing and incomplete files that were previously added but then later changed. For example, I noticed often that when running amplify env checkout main, the `backend-config.json` files would change and `team-provider-info.json` would change, then I'd have a merge conflict when running git merge dev. I think in one of those actions I have this situation described on StackOverflow

So to attempt to fix this, I ran:

1. Got all the files/folders that were deleted (on dev but not on the newly merged master) `git diff dev --name-status | grep D > deleted_files`
2. Output list of all files and folders `git log --name-status > file_history` Gonna be using this to figure out the last updated version of the deleted file.
3. Go through the list of deleted_files one by one, find the most updated version in file_history, and restore it. Example: `git checkout 25b8a44 view.php 25b8a44...` was the commit with the last updated version of view.php. I tried `cherry-pick` and just a straight git checkout dev view.php but I found explicitly using the commit id, it merge more of its history. (Including the commit that cause the file to be deleted in the first place.)
4. Once all the deleted files are back a quick check `git diff dev --name-status | grep D` shows that all files are copied over. Then like Walter said an amend commit `git commit --amend` :)

This worked almost like a charm, but then I got these errors while trying to push to the main env.

[image: Amplify Preview of changes when runnning amplify push]

As you can see, there are missing features that are preventing it from running like the error: `Could not find value for parameter deploymentBucketName` and also `Could not find value for parameter s3key`

So working between the two environments is getting very frustrating and I get nervous making any infrastructure changes to the main since It might have these git conflicts and won't update to reflect dev.

Any best practices when working with two environments?